# Rust regex pattern - unrecognized escape pattern

Tags: regex, rust

I do have following string:

```
\"lengthSeconds\":\"2664\"
```

which I would like to match with this regexp:

```
Regex::new("lengthSeconds\\\":\\\"(\\d+)\\\"")
```

I even tried this:

```
Regex::new(r#"lengthSeconds\":\"(\d+)\""#)
```

but I'm getting this:

```
regex parse error:
lengthSeconds\":\"(\d+)\"
             ^^
error: unrecognized escape sequence
```

What's wrong with the regexp pattern?

Comment: use `r#"\\"lengthSeconds\\":\\"2664\\""#`

Comment: Could you post a bit more code, possibly executable on https://play.rust-lang.org/? (Just to make sure that we understand what should actually be escaped and what not.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

By using r#..#, you treat your string as a raw string and hence do not process any escapes. However, since backslashes are special characters in Regex, the Regex expression itself still requires you to escape backslashes. So this

`Regex::new(r#"\\"lengthSeconds\\":\\"(\d+)\\""#)`

is what you want.

Alternatively, you could write

`Regex::new("\\\\\"lengthSeconds\\\\\":\\\\\"(\\d+)\\\\\"").unwrap();`

to yield the same result.

See this [example on Rust Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=5a331d1f44bc714c07bfdb379169f69c)

Comment: Thank you. Dumb question. Backslashes are the only one I need to excape in rawstrings?

Comment: This answer is misleading. The backslashes need to be escaped because the regex requires it, not because the raw string requires it.

Comment: @RolandIllig Thanks for the feedback. I've tried to clarify this in the recent edit.

Comment: Your answer still doesn't clearly say that the backslashes are needed for the regex. That's the source of confusion here, and your answer should explain that.

Answer (score 3):

You only need to escape the `\` in the regex and can then use a raw string.

`r#"\\"lengthSeconds\\":\\"2664\\""#` is a valid regex which matches `\"lengthSeconds\":\"2664\"`

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=a0e29de924fc69d2037a32a3b309b91b)

Answer (score 3):

The string you want to match is:

```
\"lengthSeconds\":\"2664\"
```

To make a regular expression that matches exactly this string, you need to escape all characters that have a special meaning in regexes. In this case, it is only the backslash. The regular expression is:

```
\\"lengthSeconds\\":\\"2664\\"
```

To put this regular expressing into a Rust string literal, you need to escape all characters that have a special meaning in Rust string literals. In this case, it's the quote and the backslash. The string literal is thus:

```
"\\\\\"lengthSeconds\\\\\":\\\\\"2664\\\\\""
```

Since this is very hard to read, you should rather put the regex into a raw string literal. For this you need to escape all characters that have a special meaning in Rust raw string literals, which luckily are none. The raw string literal is thus:

```
r#"\\"lengthSeconds\\*:\\"2664\\""#
```